# Neo4j : Clarification needed about Data Size of Neo4j

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, neo4j, graph-databases

In Neo4j, data sizes are as follows. [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/capabilities-capacity.html#capabilities-data-size)

#### Data Size of Neo4j

- nodes                   : 235 (? 34 billion)
- relationships         : 235 (? 34 billion)
- properties             : 236 to 238 depending on property types 
  (maximum ? 274 billion, always at least ? 68 billion)
- relationship types : 215 (? 32 000)

I'm new to the graph database and I need to know more clarification about these values.

1. "Relationship 34 Billion" means, Whole relationships in entire database or relationships per node?
2. "Properties 274 billion" means, Whole properties in entire database or properties per node?
3. "Relationship types 32 000" means, Whole relationships types in entire database or relationships types per node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the sizes are for the entire database.

This is because there are 35 bits for storing the ID's for nodes and relations.

```
2 exponent 35 makes: 34,359,738,368
```

Answer (score 4):

Amending Ron's correct answer:

The current capacity is limited by a pointer width. There is nothing preventing form extending the pointer length, however this is always a tradeoff between capacity and overhead.

I'm expecting future versions of Neo4j using a different pointer size and therefore offering way larger capacity.